# The "ProtoCompile" task could not be initialized with its input parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I am getting the compile error below after updated my Grpc.AspNetCore to 2.40.00. What am I missing?

```
23>C:\...\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.40.0\build\_protobuf\Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(291,7): error MSB4064: The "AdditionalProtocArguments" parameter is not supported by the "ProtoCompile" task loaded from assembly: Protobuf.MSBuild, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad from the path: C:\...\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.32.0\build\_protobuf\net45\Protobuf.MSBuild.dll. Verify that the parameter exists on the task, the <UsingTask> points to the correct assembly, and it is a settable public instance property.
    23>C:\...\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.40.0\build\_protobuf\Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB4063: The "ProtoCompile" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
    23>Done building project "QLAPIBroker.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: What you miss is a bug report at the official support forum for them. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is with the version of package Grpc.AspNetCore downgrade to 2.27.0 it will work. Thats work for me

Comment: Thanks Vinit Koushik. I realized that's what I needed to do and it worked for me too.